# wxpython redirect the text to the textctrl in real-time

Tags: wxpython

wxpython how to redirect the text to the textctrl in real-time

I know how to redirect the text , but the textctrl show the text until the process end, I want to show the text in real-time

```
import sys,time
import wx

class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self,aWxTextCtrl):
        self.out=aWxTextCtrl

    def write(self,string):
        self.out.WriteText(string)


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "wxPython Redirect Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100),
                          style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Push me!')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton, btn)

        # Add widgets to a sizer        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        # redirect text here
        redir=RedirectText(log)
        sys.stdout=redir

    def onButton(self, event):        
        print "You pressed the button!"
        time.sleep(5)
        print "======End====="

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

can you give me a full example code. I need it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're looking for. Your code does redirect text in real-time as is. And it looks like you are already using my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/01/01/wxpython-redirecting-stdout-stderr/) which shows how to redirect stdout. That article should have been enough to get you going in most situations.

You may also find this other article helpful though:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/05/python-running-ping-traceroute-and-more/

It shows how to redirect text from subprocesses to your text control.